# Use the default route with Zend Router by default

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I configure Zend_Controller_Router to use the default route by default? For whatever reason unknown, it uses the current route.

This is causing some annoying routing issues, and I don't feel like editing hundreds of links to explicitly use the default route is a reasonable solution to add one custom route.

Comment: Maybe you should add some of your code, and an example of a request and the route you want it to take. Because now, what you're saying doesn't seem to make any sense (the default route - as the name implies - *is*, well, the default route). BTW, did you check [ZF - Default routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.default-routes)?

Comment: I think he means the URL helper.

Comment: The URL Helper is a part of it, but it's not the component causing the issue. If a named route is not provided, the router uses the current route instead of the default route. The URL Helper just proxies this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't obvious and is confusing, I will try though.

I am going to assume you do not mean `Zend_Controller_Route` but in fact are talking about links generated in your views.

You can use `baseUrl()` like this

```
<a href="<?=$this->baseUrl("about-us")?>">About Us</a>
```

You can set the `baseUrl` in your Bootstrap like this

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setBaseUrl("/");
```

If you are working locally you may want to set it to something like this

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setBaseUrl("/my-app/public");
```

Using `baseUrl()` in your views will now use that path to base all your URLs on. Remember you must wrap your links in `baseUrl()` for this to work.

The `url()` helper is not useful for this, this is used for doing things like pagination where you want the current parameters of the request object to be maintained.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually do mean Zend_Controller_Route
If I have a named route 'profile' every link on that page will be broken because by default it tries to use the profile route to map those URLs. I want it to use the 'default' route as is the behaviour on every other page without a named route.

Comment: use `baseUrl` then? You have used `url` incorrectly in your site.

Answer (score 0):

From Matthew Weier O'Phinney:

> The logic you quote above is within
>   the assemble() method. assemble() may
>   be called with or without routing
>   having occurred. By default, the
>   assumption is that if no route name is
>   provided, the currently matched route
>   is utilized -- and if matching was
>   never performed (or no route matched),
>   the 'default' route will be used.
>
> The rationale for using the currently
>   matched route is that typically you
>   will be routing within the same schema
>   -- as an example, if you are within a RESTful paradigm, the majority of your
>   links will be within the current
>   resource. If we were to follow your
>   suggestion to utilize the "default"
>   route when no route is specified (at
>   least, that's how I interpret what you
>   said), because the Rest_Route is not
>   the default route, every single call
>   to assemble() would require using the
>   route name -- which others would
>   deride as causing "headaches."
>
> Personally, I prefer to be explicit
>   and *always* specify the route name;
>   this way I know exactly what route I'm
>   targetting during assemble(), which
>   makes debugging easier.

Sounds like the only solution is to set the route for each link to use 'default' instead of leaving it NULL.